# Nhibernate Subclass stored as metadata

Tags: c#, nhibernate, subclass

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractFoo
{        
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : AbstractFoo
{
    public virtual string MyProp {get; set; }
}
```

I represent it like that in my hibernate mapping file :

```
<class name="AbstractFoo">
 <id name="Id">
   <generator class="native" />
 </id>
 <discriminator column="FooType" type="String" />

 <subclass name="Foo" discriminator-value="MoveFile">
     <property name="MyProp" />
 </subclass>
</class>
```

From this point, it works fine.

What I would like to do is to store every property from my subclass as metadata. I mean i want to serialize it and store it as xml, so i can have as many subclasses I want without having one table for each, nor having a lot of columns that will not be use.

Thanks.

Comment: are you aware of the implications? Querying will be near impossible with this and understanding and debugging will be magnitudes harder. reusing columns in different subclasses is probably much more efficient and easier to understand

Comment: yes i understand the implication of this. My purpose is not to query the properties that i've serialize, it's only parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<subclass name="Foo" discriminator-value="MoveFile">
  <property name="SerialisedProps" column="serialisedProps" access="Name.Space.FakeAccessor, Asse" />
</subclass>

class FakeAccessor : IPropertyAccessor, IGetter, ISetter
{
    public IGetter GetGetter(string name)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public ISetter GetSetter(string name)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool CanAccessThroughReflectionOptimizer { get { return false; } }

    public object Get(object target)
    {
        return Serialize(target);
    }
    object GetForInsert(object owner, IDictionary mergeMap, ISessionImplementor session)
    {
        return Get(owner);
    }

    public void Set(object target, object value)
    {
        // deserialize xml and set appropriate properties
    }

    Type ReturnType { get { return typeof(string); } }

    string PropertyName { get { return "SerialisedProps"; } }

    private string Serialize(object subclass)
    {
        // example implementation
        var type = subclass.GetType();
        var root = new XElement(type.Name);
        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            root.Add(new XElement("property", new XAttribute("name", prop.name), new XAttribute("value", prop.GetValue(subclass, null) + ""));
        }
        return root.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems pretty awesome. Gonna try it;